# Change CSS of Dynamic List Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

**===UPDATE===**

*If I remove `the style="display: none;` from the template and apply the below method as recommended below, the empty container fires when you click on any other list item. What else can be done?*

I have an ul list that is dynamically created at run time using jQuery and JSON (Using inline HTML is a template). I need the background CSS style to change when a user clicks on a list item (#navItem).  I've tried everything under the moon that I can think of from inline class to .appentTo(), etc. What I have below works fine for hard-coded elements but Nothing seems to work with dynamically loaded content. Whats even more confusing is that the classes in the elements within the li tag initiate...???

Any help would be appreciated. Below are my code snippets. Thnx.

HTML:

```
<div id="navScrollContainer" class="navContentPosition">
    <ul id="navContent">
    // Display as 'None' to prevent a empty containter from showing -->
        <li id="navItem" class="ulFx" style="display: none;">//<-THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE ONCLICK!!
            <a class="navA">
            <h1 class="navH1">.</h1>
            <h2 class="navH2">.</h2>
            <p class="navP">.</p>
            <hr class="navHR" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#navScrollContainer').on('click', '.ulFx', function() {
        $(this).addClass("liFx");
    });
</script>
```

This is the Function that injects the data into the DOM as a list:

```
function loadNav(url, container, appendE) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

        $.each(data.items, function() {
            var newItem = $('#' + container).clone();
            // Now fill in the fields with the data
                    newItem.addClass('ulFx');
            newItem.find("h1").text(this.label);
            newItem.find("h2").text(this.title);
            newItem.find("p").text(this.description);
            newItem.find("a").attr("href", this.gotoURL);
            newItem.children().appendTo('#' + appendE);
        });

        $('#navHeaderTitle').text(data.listTitle);
        iniScroll('scrollNav', 'navScrollContainer');
        var target = data.targetKey;
        // transition("#" + pageName, "show");
    });
};
```

The CSS that need to happen (only on that item) when the user clicks on a Item:

```
@-webkit-keyframes
liBG {from {
    background-color: transparent
}
50% { background-color: rgba(51,102,255,0.15); }
to {
    background-color: transparent
}
}

.liFx {
    -webkit-animation-name: liBG;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

The Class atributes given to the li items:

```
.navH1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFA500;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.navH2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #999999;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navP {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.navA {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navHR {
    border: none;
    background-color: #336;
    height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Gets put into the `newItem.find("a").attr("href", this.gotoURL);` from  a db via php to json. ie: ' "gotoURL":"javascript:navClickListener('bodyContent', dns + '\/wiki\/index.php\/Airworthiness_Directive #content'); '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another div and an addClass() method to my function along with [Jeff B's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10046867/742030). If the class is hard coded into the tag, it doesnt function.

```
<ul id="navContent">
    <li id="navItem" style="display: none;">
        <div>//ADDED THIS TAG TO EXCEPT THE CLASS
            <a>
                <h1>.</h1>
                <h2>.</h2>
                <p>.</p>
                <hr/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my js file:

```
$.each(data.items, function() {
    var newItem = $('#' + container).clone();
    // Now fill in the fields with the data
    newItem.find("div").addClass("ulFx");//ADDED THIS METHOD
    newItem.find("h1").text(this.label);
    newItem.find("h2").text(this.title);
    newItem.find("p").text(this.description);
    newItem.find("a").attr("href", this.gotoURL);
    newItem.children().appendTo('#' + appendE);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This will watch for dynamic elements:

```
$(".liFx").live("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("liBG");
});
```

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()` in the latest versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your click handler, I can only speculate.  However, generally when the problem is related to dynamic content and having them respond to stimulus, the problem lies in how you are attaching the handler.

If you use `.click()`, or `.trigger('click')`, the handler will be applied directly to the elements you are calling these functions on.  That means that if the elements do not currently exist, they will not receive a handler.

The way to get around this, is to attach the event listener to a parent element that will always exist and then watch for the event propagating up from the dynamic child element.  You could do this manually, by looking at the `event.target`, but jQuery, as usual, makes this easy for us.

The modern jQuery way of doing this is using `.on()` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on)):

```
$('#someparent').on('click', '#childselector', function() {
   // my handler code
});
```

jQuery then attaches a handler on `#someparent`, and when it sees a click that was targeted at `#childselector`, it fires.

If you want to apply a class to a child of `#navContent`, and `#navContent` will always exist, do this:

```
$('#navContent').on('click', 'li', function() {
     $(this).addClass("liFx");
});
```

If `#navContent` is dynamic too, simply go higher in the DOM tree.

As a side note, I notice that the `li` has an id of `navItem`.  This sounds an awful lot like a class, rather than an ID.  If you are going to have more than one `navItem`, they cannot all have  the same ID.  This is what classes are for:

```
<li class="navItem liFx" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: @Sam Tyson I know this is how it should be done but some reason its not fireing. I've tried every combo I can think of. Currently I added `$('#navContent').on('click', '.liFx', function() {$(this).addClass("liFX");});` to the bottom of the body. If I go up one parent '$('#navScrollContainer').on('click','#navContent',function() {$(this).addClass("liFx");});' , It does as expected; lights up all the items - not the one selected. Anything else I could have wrong?

Comment: @Sam Tyson I've even tried adding `newItem.find("li").addClass('liFx');` and such to my loadNav function

Comment: @Andaero, you are waiting for `liFx` to be clicked and then adding class `liFx`.  That doesn't make sense.  The selector after `click` is the selector of what you want to be clicked.  Try: `$('#navContent').on('click', 'li', function(){ $(this).addClass("liFX"); });`

Comment: Thnx - tried li already and no fire. And sorry that was a type-o in my edit.

Comment: Thnx for you help, it contributed to my [answer/finding below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046875/742030).

Comment: It seems you have a number of issues with your code.  For instance, your `a` link does not have a closing tag, and you clone an item that has an ID, but don't change the ID.  I hobbled together an example using *most* of your code, with some fixes here: http://jsfiddle.net/RrQp6/2/

Comment: This is for touch devices. There is a closing a tag if you look at the code. Adding a link into a div tag with getJSON() does not work either so the a tag has to be used around the content in-order to make the entire list item function as a link.

Comment: Then why aren't you using jQuery mobile?  Either way, it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RrQp6/4/  You could also do a `click` or `tap` event on the list item which activates the link inside.

Comment: This is a govt project on a Android device and jQueryMobile, Sencha and alike run poorly to their specs.  There is more to the big picture than the little snippets given here and the typical functions that are easy-peasy normally don't work here - it has been tried so work-arounds are needed. thnx

Comment: I understand.  But, I can only comment on the information I have.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where is the problem, but you are trying to do something as such:

```
$("#navlink").on('click', function() {
     $("#yourselector").css("backgroundColor", "#ddd"); //change the color
});
```